# Como podria solucionar este error? Exit code -1073741819

Tags: reactjs, azure, pipeline, devops

hace poco estaba haciendo el flujo normal de mi proyecto y a la hora de hacer el deploy a produccion me sale este error el cual no sabria bien como solucionarlo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

e hecho varios deploy y es primera vez que me sucede este error.

> "2023-02-24T15:37:34.6269289Z ##[error]Exit code -1073741819 returned from process: file name 'C:\azagent\A8\externals\node10\bin\node.exe', arguments '"C:\azagent\A8_work_tasks\DownloadBuildArtifacts_a433f589-fce1-4460-9ee6-44a624aeb1fb\0.217.1\main.js"'.
> "

Comment: Puede ser útil: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/solved-error-code-1073741819-when-running-certain/76b4c0e8-c5ff-43cd-9098-0ae524b422ac

Answer (score 0):

en mi experiencia con Azure DevOps me ha pasado alguna vez algo parecido cuando por ejemplo accedo a esa carpeta física para ver algo. Luego se vuelve a ejecutar la release: aquí quiere borrar el contenido de esa carpeta para volver a bajar el artefacto y te dan este tipo de errores. En mi caso la solución ha sido solo cerrar la carpeta y volver a ejecutarlo.
Si este no es el caso, puedes ir a la pipeline ver si se ha creado correctamente el artefacto:
[image: Ver]